# Error in getting JSON response from WSO2 DSS server where it contains a bit/boolean: “Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter”

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am getting the following error when I request a JSON response from **WSO2 DSS 3.5.0** service. The same thinng used to happen with WSO2 DSS 3.2.2

```
 {
  "Fault": {
    "faultcode": "soapenv:Server",
    "faultstring": "Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter",
    "detail": ""
  }
}
```

I noticed that this is happening when response contains a bit/boolean value. When I remove the latter the data is returned correctly in JSON.

Can any one help?

Comment: can you share an expected sample response and the DS xml?

Comment: <docs xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <doc>
        <userID>456</userID>
     ....
        <emailAddress></emailAddress>
        <description>Female</description>
        <mobileNumber></mobileNumber>
        <telephoneNumber></telephoneNumber>
        <dob>1966-09-25T01:00:00.000+01:00</dob>
        <isActive>false</isActive>
        <isDeceased>false</isDeceased>
        `code`<isDoctor>true</isDoctor<messageBox>259924324234234234234234234234242342342368</messageBox>
    </doc>
</docs>

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, can you share the query you use?